# What alternatives are there for easier access to {, [, \ in non-US keyboard mappings?

Tags: vim, keyboard, special-characters

All my life as a developer I was annoyed that on german keyboards some common programming characters are mapped to very awkward combinations:

- `[` = <kbd>AltGr</kbd> + <kbd>8</kbd>
- `]` = <kbd>AltGr</kbd> + <kbd>9</kbd>
- `{` = <kbd>AltGr</kbd> + <kbd>7</kbd>
- `}` = <kbd>AltGr</kbd> + <kbd>0</kbd>
- `\` = <kbd>AltGr</kbd> + <kbd>ß</kbd>

As I'm touch typing with 10 fingers, I regularly have to leave the standard finger position to type the above characters. While I've somehow got used to it, it still makes me shiver whenever I have to type lengthy combinations of the above symbols.

There are suggestions to use [US keyboard layout](http://blog.strug.de/2010/06/german-developer-should-use-this-keyboard-layout/) instead but this again makes it very hard to type the umlauts `äöüÄÖÜß`.

So i wonder: What smart solutions have other non-english developers come up with to avoid these awkward shortcuts?

I'm primarily interested in workarounds for Windows. But as a vim user I'd also like to hear vim-only solutions.

Comment: you might want to read http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Making_Parenthesis_And_Brackets_Handling_Easier or install autopairs http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3599

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/4392705 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/8704610.

Comment: I ended up going with a US-based keyboard but edited to have easy access to the non-US characters I need via AltGr, e.g. in your case the umlauts. I found https://www.kbdedit.com/ to be great for this and worth the few $$.

Answer (score 4):

Not an actual workaround, but an alternative solution that works well for me: use the US keyboard layout for programming.

Vim's choice of keys is closely related to the US keyboard layout. On a US keyboard,

- `/` is to `?` (<kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>/</kbd>) what `n` is to `N`;
- `/` is extremely convenient to reach, and unshifted;
- `{` and `}` are in the same place as `[` and `]`, they differ only in shifting;
- `+` "line down" and `-` "line up" are adjacent;
- `:` is on the home row;
- `<` and `>` are neighbours;
- *all* characters commonly used in programming are accessible with <kbd>Shift</kbd>, there is *never* any need for <kbd>AltGr</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd> etc. combos.

The last point is especially important. Vim's command language is about eliminating modifier keys so having to use only the <kbd>Shift</kbd> modifier is good.

At some point I realized how my keyboard layout held me back. I switched to the US keyboard layout for programming only. I have been doing all my programming and terminal hacking in the past few years on a US layout and I'm very happy with it. Whenever I need to write an email or make notes I can just switch back. The keyboard layout is like a representation of the mindset I'm currently in: US for programming, native for other things.

I say, give it a try.

Comment: Thanks, but what do you do if you have to type Umlauts during programming, for example for user messages?

Comment: Switching is a matter of hitting one key in my setup. I admit that it can be annoying, though. On my new job I have colleagues writing their comments in German so I have to do a lot more switching these days. Still worth it.

Answer (score 3):

Not only for that reason, but because of the better layout, I learned the *dvorak for programmers* layout. I *don't* recommend you to learn the whole layout - it took me monthes to reach my old qwertz-speed.

But the sticking point why this layout is explicitly recommended for programmers is the alignment of the numbers-row. The numbers are in shift-position whereas the symbols are in first position (but in a better alignment as in standard-qwertz and even qwerty). So for example if I hit the qwertz-<kbd>5</kbd> I get <kbd>(</kbd> instead, <kbd>8</kbd> is <kbd>)</kbd> and so on.
[Here](http://www.kaufmann.no/roland/dvorak/images/dvp1.png) you can see the whole layout.

You also have to leave the "normal" keys and reach the numbers-row, but if you train it a bit, it feels really awesome inside vim and while programming.

So one option is to **customize your standard-qwertz layout** (maybe using the [Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/906c31e4-d5ea-7988-cb39-7b688880d7cb) or any other tool) to get the special keys better positioned, like for example in the dvorak for programmers layout.

Another option is using **qwerty** and **remapping the german umlauts** to <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> for <kbd>ä</kbd>, <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> for <kbd>ß</kbd> and so on. That's what I also did with dvorak.
It's not that handy as on standard qwertz, but those characters don't occure that often, I think.